# How to report sample size of an experimental study in a thesis based on power analysis?

Tags: sample

I am not sure whether I have reported the sample size properly in my thesis which I have calculated based on power analysis.  Please a have  look:

Based on a power analysis, the desired sample size for this study was 128. Given an expected medium effect size of .5 and p < .05 (Cohen, 1992), this lead to acceptable power of .99 (Cohen, 1999). The ultimate sample size (n = 161) exceeds the number of subjects required to have sufficiently acceptable statistical power.